# In restrict linear model, why Cov($A^T(X^TX)^-X^TY$) is positive definite?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model, matrix, covariance-matrix

In restricted linear model, we have
$$Y = X\beta+\varepsilon$$
$$A^T\beta=b$$

Where $A^T\beta$ is estimable (i.e., there exists a matrix $D$, such that $D^TX=A^T$) and $A$ is a $p\times q$ matrix with rank($A$)$=q$.

The estimation of $\beta$ is

$$\hat\beta = \beta_0 - (X^TX)^-A(A^T(X^TX)^-A)^{-1}(A^T\beta_0-b),$$
where $\beta_0=(X^TX)^-X^TY$.

My question is why $A^T(X^TX)^-A$ has a inverse. I know $A^T(X^TX)^-A$ is equal to the covariance matrix $\text{cov}(A^T(X^TX)^-X^TY)$ here. So could we prove that the covariance matrix is positive definite? Could any one tell me how to do it please? Thanks.

Comment: Because covariance matrix of *any* vector is positive definite?

Comment: @Richard Hardy All covariance matrices are positive semidefinite, not necessarily positive definite.

Comment: Thanks. The covariance matrix can be semi-positive definite. I thin the condition rank$(A) = q$ can ensure the covariance matrix be positive definite, but I dont know why

Comment: If the claim is true, you need to show that the covariance is full rank, i.e., nonsingular, which would make it positive definite.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, right, of course. I thought the question was simpler and the difference could be ignored, but now I see the difference is actually at the heart of the question.

Comment: What are $A^T$ and $b$?  Are they fixed or are they some variable? What is the meaning of $(X^TX)^-$ it is not an ordinary inverse is it? Otherwise you get to $A^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY=b$. Are you talking about minimizing $Y-X\hat\beta$ restricted to $A^T\hat\beta=b$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. $A^T$ and $b$ are fixed,  $(X^TX)^−$ is the generalized inverse.

Comment: How do you apply the covariance operator on a single (vector matrix?) Cov(x)? What is the meaning of Cov(x)?

Comment: It may be helpful to you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

Comment: Is $(X^TX)^-X^TY$ gonna be different from $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$?

Comment: For covariance matrices, the distinction between positive-definite and positive-semidefinite is identical to the distinction between invertible and singular.  The invertibility is practically the same as the definition of estimable, because both are equivalent to full column rank.

Answer (score 1):

The covariance matrix in a restricted least squares problem is not positive definite as it is not full rank; the coefficients have to satisfy the linear constraints, e.g., $\beta_1 + \beta_2 = 0$, and this is sufficient to ensure that the rank of the covariance matrix is $p-q$ where there are $p$ variables and $q$ linear constraints (unless your constraints are redundant, which we will assume they are not) while having dimension $p \times p$.

You have slightly misapplied the generalized inverse as well. $X^TX$ is full rank (by assumption) so the usual inverse $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exists.

The actual covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}$ is not $A^T(X^TX)^{-1}A$ but:

$$\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}\left(I - A[A^T(X^TX)^{-1}A]^{-1}A^T(X^TX)^{-1}\right)$$

a derivation of which can be found in many places, including http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/Restricted_Testing_000.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. In this setting, we do not have $X^TX$ is full rank, so how to show $A^T(X^TX)^−A$ has a inverse?

Comment: Just use the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse; it is the same as the regular inverse when the matrix is full rank, and possesses all the desirable properties when it isn't.  You can't guarantee that $A^T(X^TX)^-A$ has full rank if the inner matrix does not; imagine that $A = I$ for example and you can see that the regular inverse won't exist if $X$ is less than full rank.

Comment: We assume that $A^T = D^T X$, so $A^T(X^TX)^−A = D^TX(X^TX)^−X^TD =\text{cov}(A^T(X^TX)−X^TY)$. Could it be used to solve the problem?

Comment: But without assumptions about $D$ you're still doomed.  You can't, for example, ensure that $A \neq I$, which it can be by making the "first part" of $D^T$ equal to the inverse of the "first part" of $X$ and the rest of $D^T$ equal to $0$.